# Newly posted photos/albums are not publicly available

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

When a album is created and filled with photos for a page of which I am the admin, the album and images are not publicly visible.
The scope is set to manage_pages and publish_stream.

Is there anything I could do to make the album and all photos publicly browsable/visible ?

```
// create album
$albumArgs = array(
   'message' => 'A new album',
   'name' => $albumName,
   'privacy' =>  '{"value" :"EVERYONE"}',
   'access_token' => $accessToken
);          
$album = $facebook->api('/'.$user_profile['id'].'/albums', 'post', $albumArgs);

// add photo
$photoArgs = array(
   'message' => 'New photo',
   'image' => '@'.realpath($entry->picture),
   'privacy' =>  '{"value" :"EVERYONE"}',
   'access_token' => $accessToken
);
$result = $facebook->api('/'.$album['id'].'/photos', 'post', $photoArgs);
```

Comment: When you say 'not publicly visible' - what privacy settings are on them? are they retrievable via the api when you use the ID you get back as the result of the POST request?

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this one. I've been testing and looking around for days now and have not found a working solution, albeit the abundance of answers 8-/